# How to calculate the interior value of triangular element in edge (vector) finite element?

Tags: finite-element, electromagnetism, unstructured-mesh

I was using an edge (vector) finite element to solve electromagnetic diffusion (two-dimensional cases). The element that I used was a triangular element. I have got the result of the finite element in each edges element of the triangular element. But I don't know how to extract the value interior the triangular element.

How can I get the value interior the triangular element (in $x$ and $y$ directions)??

Comment: Not only for this particular case, but in general, the solution to a finite element problem is a linear combination of the basis functions $\phi_i(x)$, e.g. the approximate solution $u(x)=\sum \alpha_i\phi_i(x)$ for $\alpha_i\in\mathrm{R}$. That is basically the way how you can get the value of the solution inside the element.

Comment: Yes, I know about the linear combination. Let's say I already have the basis function and used it to build the sensitivity matrices (K) and I have done the calculation of linear equation K x = b where b is the bounndary condition. I got the result of x (the magnetic field that I want to calculate using finite element) in each edges of each elements. Then, I want to calculate the magnetic field (in x dan y directions) for each elements so I calculate the value inside the element and I don't know how to do it. Maybe could you give me some example or references??@AbdullahAliSivas

Comment: Can you extend your question with the particular basis you use or provide a reference? I can give you a concrete answer in that case.

Comment: I use vector trinagular basis function like in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268357028_Mixed_formulations_formulations_using_mixed_elements_in_electromagnetics_via_the_finite_element_method_The_case_of_modeling_tokamak_plasmas_in_a_computational_electromagnetic_environment and the math that I want to solve using finite element is magnetic filed in this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325044654_The_Use_of_Sparse_Direct_Solver_in_Vector_Finite_Element_Modeling_for_Calculating_Two_Dimensional_2-D_Magnetotelluric_Responses_in_Transverse_Electric_TE_Mode

Comment: Then I want to calculate value of the magnetic field interior of triangular element to extract the value of magnet field in z and y direction like in that paper. @AbdullahAliSivas could you give me the concrete answer of that case?

Comment: It is late where I am, so I am going to give a quick comment and come back to this sometime tomorrow. Looks like you are using linear triangular Nedelec basis functions. Referring to page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4618.pdf, assuming you have the coefficients $\beta_i$, the solution inside the element $K$ can be found by the formula $\sum_i \beta_i B_K^{-T}\hat{\eta}^{\text{Ned}}_i(F_K^{-1}(x))$.